# Rails 3 issuing an ajax POST followed by a GET to the same URL

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

As seen below, I'm in a Rails 3.1 app attempting to POST with a link_to using a block:

views/wall/_problem.html.erb

```
<li data-icon="check">
<%= link_to(
  url_for(
    :controller => 'completed_problems',
    :action => 'create',
    :problem_id => "#{problem.id}"),
  {:class => "wall_problem",
  :confirm => "Climbed it?",
  :remote => true,
  :"data-type" => "json",
  :method => "POST"}) do %>
<div>stuff</div>
<% end %>
</li>
```

views/wall/show.html.erb

```
<% content_for :content do %>
  <div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview">
    <%= render :partial => 'problem', :collection => @wall.live_problems.sort %>
  </ul>
<% end %>

<script>
  $('.wall_problem').live('ajax:success', function() {
    alert("Success!");
  });
</script>
```

This particular POST is directed to the following controller action:

controllers/completed_problems_controller.rb

```
class CompletedProblemsController < ApplicationController
  # POST /completed_problems
  def create
    @problem = Problem.find(params[:problem_id]
    @completed_problem = @problem.completed_problems.build
    if @completed_problem.save
      render :json => { }
    else
      render :json => { :location => root_url}
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see from the logs below, the POST does succeed as it should, but for some reason the app executes a GET to the exact same URL at the same time.

LOGS

```
Started POST "/completed_problems?problem_id=11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-11 13:13:06 -0500
  Processing by CompletedProblemsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"problem_id"=>"11"}
  # SQL stuff snipped from here
Completed 200 OK in 116ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)

Started GET "/completed_problems?problem_id=11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-11 13:13:06 -0500
  Processing by CompletedProblemsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"problem_id"=>"11"}
Rendered completed_problems/index.html.erb within layouts/application (29.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 36ms
```

The problem does sound similar in scope to [jQuery ajax POST causes an immediate GET to the same URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243311/jquery-ajax-post-causes-an-immediate-get-to-the-same-url) but this is using jquery_ujs and I don't believe I've left any custom jquery code sitting around.  As such, I can't perform the solution suggested in that problem of adding a 'return false;'

I suspect that issue is in one of three places:

1. I have incorrect syntax for using the link_to element with a block
2. My handling of the request within the controller is incorrect
3. I somehow have doubled my jquery_ujs (which I really don't think to be true, but it could be here)

***EDIT***

Narrowing down the problem #1:

I changed my script to the following,

```
<script>
  $('.wall_problem').live('ajax:beforeSend', function() {
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

And discovered that the POST now did not go through, but the GET did, confirming that problem seems to be that the AJAX handler is picking up the link and submitting it as a POST properly, but is not intercepting the GET that the browser submits.

Narrowing down the problem #2:

I did not mention it at first, but I am using Jquery-mobile.  Now in restoring the script tag to its previous form and then disabling jquery-mobile, I have tried the link again and it now does not submit the GET but does submit the POST.  That leads me to believe that there's some issue with how jquery-ujs and jquery mobile are interacting with the link.

Comment: Does one problem have many completed_problems? Or, is the problem completed or not completed. If it is the later I'd just have a boolean in the Post table to say if it was completed or not. Then you could just make a simple AJAX call to the problems_controller update action and set the completed property to ture or false. I am not sure if this is how your app is build, but if it is I post an answer on how you can solve it.

Comment: The CompletedProblem object is effectively a join object between user and problem, so I don't think that would help.  Doing that also seems like it would just be a work around for the larger problem.

Comment: If a user has_many problems and a problem belongs_to a user, you don't need a join. With a simple boolean field you can do scopes like `user.problems.where(:completed => false)`. It's not ment as a workaround. Simpler code => less problems. Also, you could write you own Jquery function to handle the AJAX POST and then on the response  update your view with a .js.erb template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info I included in the above edit, I continued down the path of testing Jquery Mobile and was able to solve.

First, I updated to Jquery Mobile v1.0, which adds the linkBindingEnabled global config (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html):

Second, I set that config to False:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
});
```